# Access TFS Team Query from Client Object API

Tags: c#, tfs

Is there a way to run a shared team query, by name, through the TFS 2013 client object API

I'm working on a C# script that will do some work based off of the results of a shared team query. I don't want to have to maintain the query in the TFS UI as well as in my script; I'd prefer to just run the registered query that my team uses, but then just play with the results. When I write "registered query" I'm just referring to a query that I wrote in the TFS UI and saved as a shared query.

In other words: I'd like to use the TFS UI to create a query, save the file in my "shared queries" list, call it "foo", then access foo from the client object API in my script.

I see that there is a `GetQueryDefinition(GUID)` method off of `WorkItemStore`, but where would I get the `GUID` for a shared team query?

Comment: I think this should give me what I need: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/06/16/work-item-tracking-queries-object-model-in-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sample code that should do what you need

```
///Handles nested query folders    
private static Guid FindQuery(QueryFolder folder, string queryName)
{
    foreach (var item in folder)
    {
        if (item.Name.Equals(queryName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return item.Id;
        }

        var itemFolder = item as QueryFolder;
        if (itemFolder != null)
        {
            var result = FindQuery(itemFolder, queryName);
            if (!result.Equals(Guid.Empty))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return Guid.Empty;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var collectionUri = new Uri("http://TFS/tfs/DefaultCollection");
    var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);
    var workItemStore = server.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    var teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["TeamProjectName"];

    var x = teamProject.QueryHierarchy;
    var queryId = FindQuery(x, "QueryNameHere");

    var queryDefinition = workItemStore.GetQueryDefinition(queryId);
    var variables = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"project", "TeamProjectName"}};

    var result = workItemStore.Query(queryDefinition.QueryText,variables);
}
```

Comment: FindQuery could be simiplified by removing `var itemFolder = item as QueryFolder;` and changing the following 4 lines to `if (item is QueryFolder)
   {
    Guid result = FindQuery((QueryFolder)item, queryName);
    if (result != Guid.Empty)`