# TFS JAVA SDK - How to run shared query

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have a application which useds TFS JAVA SDK 14.0.3 .
I have a shared query  on my tfs , how can i run the shared query and get the response back using TFS SDK 14.0.3

Also I could see that the query url will expire in every 90 days , so any better way to execute the shared query?

Now I  have a method to run a query , i want method  to  run shared query also.

```
public void getWorkItem(TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc, Project project){
    WorkItemClient workItemClient = project.getWorkItemClient();
    // Define the WIQL query.
    String wiqlQuery = "Select ID, Title,Assigned from WorkItems where (State = 'Active') order by Title";
    // Run the query and get the results.
    WorkItemCollection workItems = workItemClient.query(wiqlQuery);
    System.out.println("Found " + workItems.size() + " work items.");
    System.out.println();
    // Write out the heading.
    System.out.println("ID\tTitle");
    // Output the first 20 results of the query, allowing the TFS SDK to
    // page
    // in data as required
    final int maxToPrint = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < workItems.size(); i++) {
        if (i >= maxToPrint) {
            System.out.println("[...]");
            break;
        }
        WorkItem workItem = workItems.getWorkItem(i);
        System.out.println(workItem.getID() + "\t" + workItem.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Shared query is a query which has been run and saved, so what you need should be getting a a shared query, not run a shared query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared query is a query which has been run and saved, so what you need should be getting a a shared query, not run a shared query. You could refer to case [Access TFS Team Query from Client Object API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479030/access-tfs-team-query-from-client-object-api):

```
///Handles nested query folders    
private static Guid FindQuery(QueryFolder folder, string queryName)
{
    foreach (var item in folder)
    {
        if (item.Name.Equals(queryName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return item.Id;
        }

        var itemFolder = item as QueryFolder;
        if (itemFolder != null)
        {
            var result = FindQuery(itemFolder, queryName);
            if (!result.Equals(Guid.Empty))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return Guid.Empty;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var collectionUri = new Uri("http://TFS/tfs/DefaultCollection");
    var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);
    var workItemStore = server.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    var teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["TeamProjectName"];

    var x = teamProject.QueryHierarchy;
    var queryId = FindQuery(x, "QueryNameHere");

    var queryDefinition = workItemStore.GetQueryDefinition(queryId);
    var variables = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"project", "TeamProjectName"}};

    var result = workItemStore.Query(queryDefinition.QueryText,variables);
}
```

By the way, you could also check the REST API in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/queries/get